# Using a WiX property from a browse dialog

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm developing a setup project using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX), and I have the following problem. I get a directory path from the user using the Browse dialog, and I need to put this path in `web.config`. The problem is that in `web.config` that puts the value in "WWWMain" and not the path chosen by the user.

This is my code:

**Product.wxs**

```
<Property Id="IISLOGDIRECTORY" Value="WWWMain" />
```

**Dialog.wxs**

```
<Control Id="IISLogDirectoryEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="45" Y="100" Width="220" Height="18" Disabled="yes" Property="IISLOGDIRECTORY" Indirect="yes" />
```

**Installation.wxs**

```
<util:XmlFile Id="ModifyIISLogDirectory"
           Action="setValue"
           Permanent="yes"
           ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='isslogdirectory'[\]]/@value"
           File="[INSTALLLOCATION]Web\Web.config"
           Value="[IISLOGDIRECTORY]"/>
```

Comment: The problem was conceptual, so that the path will be saved correctly in the web.config as the value had to put [WWWMain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable in Dialog.wxs itself but after the control

Example

```
<Control Id="DiffBackUpEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="120"  Y="157" Width="160" Height="18" Property="IISLOGDIRECTORY">
</Control>
<Control Id="Browse12" Type="PushButton" X="290" Y="157" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Browse">
    <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="DIFFDBBACKUPLOC" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Then at bottom in same page after  add

```
<Property Id="IISLOGDIRECTORY" Value="C:\Database\MDM"/>
```