# WiX installer browse dialog doesn't update text field

Tags: wix, installation

I have the following two controls in my WiX installer that render and work correctly *most* of the time:

```
            <Control Id="LogPathEdit" Type="Edit" X="134" Y="71" Width="130" Height="15" Property="LOGPATH" Text="[LOGPATH]">
                <Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[&Server<>3]]></Condition>
                <Condition Action="show"><![CDATA[&Server=3]]></Condition>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="btnDirBrowse" Type="PushButton" Width="56" Height="17" X="268" Y="70" Text="Browse..." >
                <Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[&Server<>3]]></Condition>
                <Condition Action="show"><![CDATA[&Server=3]]></Condition>
              <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="LOGPATH" Order="1">1</Publish>
              <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
            </Control>
```

However if I edit the **LogPathEdit** text box before I browse for a directory, the text box doesn't get updated with the value selected from the browse directory dialog. If I just click on the **Browse...** button and select a directory, the text field gets updated and works correctly.

I've looked at these two links, but they don't solve my issue:

[Use WiX browser dialog to set edit box value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496995/use-wix-browser-dialog-to-set-edit-box-value)

[Using a WiX property from a browse dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118579/using-a-wix-property-from-a-browse-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Type from Edit to LogPathEdit solved the issue. Here's the new line:

```
            <Control Id="LogPathEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="134" Y="71" Width="130" Height="15" Property="LOGPATH" Text="[LOGPATH]">
```